# How to run java command through code without creating a new process?

Tags: java

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("....")
```

and

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-server", "-jar", "yourJar.jar");
Process p = pb.start();
```

The above 2 ways of executing a command create a new process for running the command.

Is there a way to execute the command in the same process, without creating a new one?

Comment: I'm not going to write up a complete answer, but the basic idea is this: Use reflection libraries to manually load a class (look up classloaders), and then instantiate the class you want, and call its main method.

Comment: Your question reminds me of the preamble to the "perlembed" manpage...

"Use Perl from Perl?
            Read about "do" in perlfunc and "eval" in perlfunc and "require" in
            perlfunc and "use" in perlfunc.

       Use C from C?
            Rethink your design."

Answer (score 3):

As @soong commented, you could manually load your JAR and the classes you need, and then call the `main` method by reflection. You can achieve this with something like this:

```
// load your JAR file as a File instance
String myJarPath = "C:\\somefolder\\someOtherFolder\\MyJar.jar";
File myJarFile = new File(myJarPath);

// create a new class loader based on your JAR's URL
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{myJarFile.toURI().toURL()});

// load the class with the main method
Class<?> classToLoad = classLoader.loadClass("MyClass");

// get the main method
Method method = classToLoad.getMethod("main", String[].class);

// invoke it
String args[] = {"arg1", "arg2"};   // args to pass to the main method, it can be null
method.invoke(null, (Object) args); // first parameter is null because main is static
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could read classes into the Process with an ObjectInputStream